# Creating a single controller for multiple WPF Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, controller

I'm very new to WPF and a beginner in C#.NET. I'm currently making an application where there will be many pages and the trigger to change the page is hand gesture using Kinect SDK (the trigger method is not relevant for this question). Normally when a WPF file is created, there will be a similarly named .cs file attached to it, which acts somewhat like a controller. However, I need multiple WPF files/pages to be controlled only by a single controller .cs file. How do I achieve that? Thanks for viewing my question and your answer will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to write a class that contains your 'controller' code and reference it from your WPF UserControls / Pages.

In a new file:

```
public class MyController
{
    public void DoThings(object parameter)
    {
        // stuff you want to do 
    }
}
```

and then inside your UserControl code-behind class:

```
public partial class MyWpfControl : UserControl
{
    private MyController controller;

    public MyWpfControl
    {
        this.controller = new MyController();
    }
}
```

and finally, tie your events back to the controller's method:

```
private void OnGesture(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call the method on the controller, and pass whatever parameters you need...
    this.controller.DoThings(e);
}
```

Comment: Although, if possible, the parameter shouldn't be `object` but some specific type.

Comment: @svick Of course - and the classes and methods should be named appropriately :)

Comment: thanks for the help but your solution is not applicable. The trigger should come from the Controller and affects the page, not the other way round.

Comment: @user1055010 then you might want to begin using the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The code behind is really part of the view and isn't really analogous to a controller and generally there shouldn't be much code in them.  Typically you would want most of your logic between your "View Model" which serves as an abstraction of the view and "Model" which serves as an abstraction of the business logic that your UI is interacting with.

In this light what I think you really want is a View Model(VM) that controls multiple views.  This is a fairly typical scenario and the preferred method (IMO anyway) is to have a hierarchical view model that has a top level the application model and a number of sub VMs that represent different components within your UI, though you can bind everything to your top level VM if you really want to.

To do this we would first define our view model like so

```
public interface IGestureSink
{
    void DoGesture();
}

public class MyControlVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, IGestureSink
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private ApplicationVM parent;
    public MyControlVM(ApplicationVM parent)
    {
        this.Name = "my user control";
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.PropertyChanged += (s, o) => PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Visible"));
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get { return parent.ControlVisible; } }
    public void DoGesture()
    {
        parent.DoGesture();
    }
}

public class ApplicationVM : INotifyPropertyChanged, IGestureSink
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public ApplicationVM()
    {
        this.ControlVM = new MyControlVM(this);
        this.ControlVisible = false;
    }
    public MyControlVM ControlVM { get; private set; }
    public bool ControlVisible {get; set;}

    public void DoGesture()
    {
        this.ControlVisible = !this.ControlVisible;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ControlVisible"));
    }
}
```

and then all we need to do is to build a user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and page

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"  x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <my:MyControl Width="200" Height="200" x:Name="myUserControl" DataContext="{Binding ControlVM}" Visibility="{Binding Visible,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="222,262,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

That use it.  The only thing that we need in our code behind is a constructor that sets up the page VM and wiring from our button to the view model.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ApplicationVM();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IGestureSink)(this.DataContext)).DoGesture();
    }
}
```

If you wanted to use a monolithic view model instead you would use this Instead of binding the DataContext to `ControlVM`:

```
<my:MyControl Width="200" Height="200" x:Name="myUserControl" DataContext="{Binding DataContext}" Visibility="{Binding ControlVisible,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```